# Tiny Lua library to get char pointer from string

Tags: c, memory-management, lua, opengl

### Background

I'm using Lua with [luaglut](https://github.com/LuaDist/luaglut) to do some OpenGL stuff. The luaglut API is almost identical to the gl/glut C APIs. Sometimes, gl functions want a pointer to some data, for example:

```c
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, oh_crap_a_pointer)
```

In these cases, the luaglut bindings take a [light userdata](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.5.html) containing the pointer. In the luaglut demos, a small example library called [memarray](https://github.com/LuaDist/luaglut/blob/master/memarray.c) does the work of setting up a C array and returning a pointer to it as a light userdata.

You might use "memarray" something like this:

```lua
require 'memarray'
function loadTexture(filename)
  local file = assert(io.open(filename, 'rb'))
  local data = file:read('*a')
  file:close()
  local array = memarray('uchar', #data)
  array:from_str(data)

  return array
end

-- ... later

local texture = loadTexture('whatever.rgba')
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture:ptr())
```

That got me thinking, why do we need memarray at all? Lua strings should be binary safe; all we really need is to get a pointer to the string returned from
`file:read('*a')` as a light userdata. It would look something like this:

```lua
function loadTexture(filename)
  local file = assert(io.open(filename, 'rb'))
  local data = file:read('*a')
  file:close()

  return data
end

-- ... later

local stringpointer = require 'stringpointer'
local texture = loadTexture('whatever.rgba')
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, stringpointer.get(texture))
```

Of course we pass the string around instead of the pointer, because the GC could free the memory the string was in if there are no more references to it, invalidating the pointer. Internally Lua strings are immutable and passed by reference anyway, so this is no big deal.

### Code

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int get_pointer(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TSTRING);
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void *)lua_tostring(L, 1));
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_stringpointer(lua_State *L)
{
    const luaL_Reg api[] = {
        {"get", get_pointer},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

#if LUA_VERSION_NUM == 501
    luaL_register(L, "stringpointer", api);
#else
    luaL_newlib(L, api);
#endif

    return 1;
}
```

It's really tiny, but my C is rusty so maybe I did something stupid. It seems to work fine so far. Any input is welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason why `int get_pointer(lua_State *L)` and `int luaopen_stringpointer(lua_State *L)` are not void functions? I cannot tell from the context if they have to return ints or not.

Comment: @bazola the int returned from `get_pointer` is the number of return values it gives when you call it from Lua. That means return the last thing on the stack, the lightuserdata pushed on the line before.

Comment: `luaopen_stringpointer` is the function Lua looks for when you `require 'stringpointer'`. The return value means the same thing there, it returns one value, a table containing a "get" function.

Comment: What does `glTexImage2D` do with the string data passed to it? Does it own it? Does it free it? Does it use it immediately? Does it use it at some, unspecified, later date?

Comment: @EtanReisner It copies the data and uses that copy later. It doesn't attempt to free the memory at the pointer you pass in. It's not really string data, it's in a somewhat arbitrary format described by the rest of the arguments.

Comment: If you know it copies the data and you never "cache" the returned pointer and try to use it at some later date yourself then I *believe* this is reasonable and safe.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no Lua expert, but I can at least give you a pointer (no pun intended) about your C code.

Your `get_pointer` function looks like it works fine, but it could be made even more concise! Lua provides a [`luaL_checkstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_checkstring) function that combines `luaL_checktype` and `luaL_tostring`. Therefore, you could just do this:

```
int get_pointer(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void *) luaL_checkstring(L, 1));
    return 1;
}
```